# Help in solving a second-order differential equation relating to gravitational waves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An exact gravitational plane wave solution to Einstein's field equation has the line metric

$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-2\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v+a^2(u)\mathrm{d}^2x+b^2(u)\mathrm{d}^2y.$$

I have calculated the non-vanishing Christoffel symbols and Ricci curvature components and used the vacuum Einstein equation to obtain

$$\frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2a}{\mathrm{d}u^2}+\frac{1}{b}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2b}{\mathrm{d}u^2}=0,$$

where $a=a(u)$ and $b=b(u)$.

How do I show using the above differential equation that an exact solution can be found, in which both $a$ and $b$ are determined in terms of an arbitrary function $f(u)$?

Comment: What is the unknown function?

Comment: I am supposed to find both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Have you tried separation of variables, i.e.  ${1\over a} a'' = f(u) = -{1\over b} b''$?